# How to make my code complying with ACID principle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, supabase

```
export const addTransaction = async (newPurchase : PurchaseType) => {
  // Create an abortcontroller
  const ac = new AbortController();

  try {
    const {error} = await supabase
    .from("purchases")
    .insert(newPurchase)
    .abortSignal(ac.signal)

    console.log('Adding a transaction...');

    if (error) throw new Error(error.message);

    await chargeUser(newPurchase.amount, newPurchase.id!)

  } catch (error : any) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // Abort the request to purchases table
    ac.abort();
    throw new Error("ล้มเหลวระหว่างการบันทึกการสั่งซื้อสินค้า");
  }
}
```

From this block of code, how do make the database transaction respecting the principle of Atomicity from ACID principle? I would like to abort the insert action to the purchases table if chargeUser() function failed to execute or throw an Error

Comment: You cannot achieve ACID transaction by calling two functions on the client side. You would need to create a Postgres function and implement all the transaction there. Once you have the function, you can call it from the client. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-transaction/

Comment: @dshukertjr Thanks mate. I will look into the article